# ¿Como encender la pantalla para mostrar una notificación?

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero que mi aplicación encienda la pantalla para que se muestre una notificación por si la pantalla el teléfono se encuentra suspendida. Estoy intentando con un wakelook pero no enciende la pantalla, pero si suena y vibra el teléfono cuando se lanza la notificación.

```
PowerManager power = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = power.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "reminders::tag");
            wl.acquire(3000);

            lanzarNotificacion();

            wl.release();
```

En el android manifest ya agregue el siguiente permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Nota: Estoy lanzando la notificación a través de un receiver de un alarmManager, por lo que no puedo usar window flags

Comment: Usa ScreenDim y AcquireCausesWakeup solamente en lugar de las que tienes puestas y también el `LanzarNotificacion()` ponlo primero antes que el PowerManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cabe mencionar un punto muy importante, para detectar si la pantalla esta apagada y en base a esto encenderla, antes de API 20 debes usar:

```
 power.isScreenOn();
```

después de la API 20 debes usar:

```
power.isInteractive()
```

por lo tanto esta sería la forma adecuada de encender la pantalla al crear la notificación:

```
  PowerManager power = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  boolean isScreenOn = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20 ? power.isInteractive() : power.isScreenOn();

 if (!isScreenOn) { //¿La pantalla esta apagada?
      //La pantalla esta apagada!, se enciende.
      PowerManager.WakeLock wl = power.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myApp:notificationLock");
      wl.acquire(3000);
      wl.release();
}else{
                //La pantalla esta encendida!
}

lanzarNotificacion();
```

por supuesto no olvidar el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```